# iFrame in a Joomla 2.5 article

Tags: joomla-2.5, articles, article-manager

I'm trying to put an iFrame (from Google Maps) in an article but it the code just appears as text. I've had a look at the HTML source and its not in any

tags or anything. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to:

**Extensions** >> **Plugin Manager** >> **TinyMCE** >> **Prohibited Elements**

The remove `iframe` from the list.

Answer (score 3):

My preferred way of doing this is to create a module for your code (using for example [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-html-advanced) or the built-in [Iframe Wrapper module](https://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Extensions_Module_Manager_Wrapper). Publish the module to a custom position (like `GoogleMap`). Then load the module into any article using this code:

```
{loadposition GoogleMap}
```

Joomla will take care of the rest, and insert the code into your article.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can change your default editor to "none".
This will give you a raw HTML format for every text you type, so tags will stay where you want them.

`Users -> *your user name* -> Basic settings -> Editor`

But if you are not that experienced with pure HTML, stay with the solution from Lodder.

Comment: I'm very experienced with HTML. Main reason I use Joomla is for Virtuemart as my company make websites for takeaways.

Comment: Then I suppose trying to change the editor as suggested. This prevents a lot of issues with WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: I don't suppose you could try answering another of my questions partly concerning an editor? - http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/virtuemart-interamind-e-mail-extension-not-accepting-html